# In C# how do I access the properties of a derived class from the derived class constructor?

Tags: c#, inheritance, datagridview, constructor

I have a `DataGridView` derived control which has some new properties defined. They show as expected in the property inspector with the connectionstring value entered, but when I compile the program if I put a break in the constructor on the: `if (ConnectionString == "" )` line - it shows `ConnectionString` is null as indeed is `connectionString`. I realise I should be testing for null after I wrote this but the point is that the property has a string in it.

The intent was to define table and `connectionString` as properties from which to populate it. What am I doing wrong?

```
namespace ASControls
{

    public partial class ASDataGridView : DataGridView  
    {

        private string connectionString; 
        // Declares the property.
        [Description("Set the Connection String for the datbase concerned"),
        Category("Data")]
        public string ConnectionString
        {
           get { return connectionString; }
           set {connectionString= value; }
        }

        public ASDataGridView()
        {
        //
        // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
        //
        InitializeComponent();

        //
        // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
        //

        if (ConnectionString == "" )
        {           
            MessageBox.Show("You must set the connection string in order to use an ASDataGridView control");
            return;
        } else {

            InitData(ConnectionString);
        }

        }
        ...
```

Comment: You might want to check the property `this.DesignMode`.. since people can't set a property in the designer if you won't allow them to use the control prior to setting it..

Comment: Thanks for coming back simon but I am not following your meaning though: currently the property is being set at design time in the property inspector!

Comment: Now I rethink this some more I really don't get the point about DesignMode at all. Why would the program be in DesignMode? The derived constructor is triggering as expected  when the form compiles (so its not in design mode) its just that the values of the properties are not as expected - I am assuming I am looking at the wrong instance but I dont know how so!

Answer (score 0):

What's Simon talking about is the fact that in the designer, you can't call your database. The solution is :

```
if (IsInDesignMode) // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
{
    StatBarTextProp = "IN Design mode";
}
else // Code runs "for real"
{
    StatBarTextProp = /* Get from DB here*/ ;
    
}
```

Now, your run time is happily fetching stuff from the DB, and your design will have whatever you default it to.

---

Yep, you can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.isindesignmode(v=vs.110).aspx), but basically:

> DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode Attached Property
>
> .NET Framework 4.5 Other Versions This topic has not yet been rated - Rate this topic
> Gets or sets whether a DependencyObject is running in the context of a designer.
>
> Namespace:  System.ComponentModel
>
> Assembly:  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)
> XMLNS for XAML: Not mapped to an xmlns.

Comment: Ok from your responses it sounds like I have misunderstood the use of the constructor. I am not intending to access the database whilst in design time at all. The idea is that when the form loads, and the derived DGV is instantiated it then uses the conectionstring with populate() to fetch the data. I gather then the constructor is called at design time then rather when the class instantiates after the form loads.

Comment: The above goes in the constructor, and the idea is to have some data instead a blank form when you are working on the VS designer. Here should come all the usual questions about frameworks, and benefits, and so on, but the idea of the designer mode is so you can have a quick view with fake data. sometimes, very useful, sometimes, not really needed

Comment: IsInDesignMode is part of WPF? Forgive the obvious lack of enlightenment on my part but can I not inherit from a core control without this layer?

Comment: I am not sure if we are on the same page here. I am not implementing a WPF application, but rather a class library. I wonder if that makes a difference, if not,  I am a bit lost about adding the PresentationFramework assembly and then using IsInDesignMode from the class! After adding the assembly I get "The name 'InDesignMode' does not exist in the current context (CS0103)". Do I need to add a using statement?

Comment: Ok, I see ... Have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7322281/1698987) then, it might be more what you're looking for. Hope it helps (leave a message if it does, and I'll include it in the answer for reference)